# Middle click is not pasting the text in terminus sublime text 3

Tags: linux, sublimetext3, sublimetext, copy-paste, sublime-text-plugin

In Linux terminal, when we select some text and middle click, the text will be pasted at the end.

I want the same thing to happen in terminus sublime text. The problem is when I select text on terminus in sublime text and middle click the text will be pasted where I middle click. If I middle click at the end and press enter the text disappears and no command will be executed.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I don't think there is much you can do aside from clicking where you want to paste.  The thing is that in terminus (or other terminal emulators) the cursor focus doesn't follow the mouse; in any "proper" GUI app (including sublime) it will/does. I don't know sublime, so can't comment on whether or not it's focus behaviour can be modified if there's a selection in the clipboard, but I'd be surprised.  As for "click at the end and press enter" - **don't**. Do middle click, cursor right, and then enter.

Answer (score 0):

The short version of the answer to this is that it's theoretically possible for this to work, but it would need to be supported by Terminus, and Terminus doesn't do this. So at the moment it's not possible generally and might even be impossible to implement in a satisfactory way.

A longer version of the answer is that as far as Sublime is concerned, a Terminus tab (or panel) is just a regular tab that is in no way special. Terminus catches key presses and commands being executed inside of the the tab, passes them to something it's running in the background, and then displays whatever the program runs responds with.

Middle clicking with the mouse on Linux fires the `paste_selection_clipboard` command, which inserts the text on the selection clipboard at the mouse location. Terminus doesn't catch that command to be able to tell that anything was pasted, and the fact that it's displayed in the window at all is entirely because Terminus isn't stopping it and Sublime doesn't know it's a special tab.

In theory Terminus could catch the command to know that the text is being inserted so that it could paste it at the current cursor location, but it doesn't currently do this and there's not an API of any sort that would tell it what the contents of the selection clipboard is (this is separate from the standard clipboard, which is accessible via plugins) which makes grabbing the text more complicated.

So quite likely the best Terminus can do is block the command from executing at all so that you don't get confused about it not taking an action.

Comment: Is there any key binding to run the code in editor into the terminus tab ?

Comment: @tejas not by default, but it's possible to make build systems that execute code in Terminus, which includes creating a tab and running the code there. The README for Terminus has information on how to do this, and also includes some links to YouTube videos that demonstrate it as well.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I was able to implement this using send_selection_to_terminus method